# Using ManyToMany through correctly for complex model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a semi complex model relationship in my django app.

I have a Group (a business) which can have many locations
So

A group can have many providers (person) as well.  The thing is, the Provider is connected to a particular group through the group location. That is to say a provider can have that location.  In reality, i believe a provider can have many locations (belonging to multiple groups).  The way I have this in my django so far which I don't think correct is this way:

```
class GroupLocations(models.Model):
    address_id = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now=false, auto_now_add=true)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=true, auto_now_add=true)

class ProviderLocations(models.Model):
    provider_id = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_location_id = models.ForeignKey(GroupLocations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now=false, auto_now_add=true)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=true, auto_now_add=true)
```

My question is, does my Group (and/or Provider) model need to have some sort of relationship specified in their model definitions?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_contact= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #do I need something like the following:
   providers = models.ManyToMany(Provider, through='ProviderLocations')
   provider_locations = models.ManyToMany(Group, through='GroupLocations'


class Provider(models.Model):
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now=false, auto_now_add=true)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=true, auto_now_add=true)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='GroupLocations')
    group_locations = models.ManyToMany(GroupLocations, through='ProviderLocations')
```

This is so i can get a list of groups from a provider, and the groups locations
and I can get a list of providers from a group and the providers locations.Actually more like the locations join which to which.    I am still learning Django'ss relationship systems so any constructive criticism of how to make these relationships work well together would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, does my Group (and/or Provider) model need to have
>   some sort of relationship specified in their model definitions?

Yes a many to many relationship. And you only need to define it for one model or the other because many to many can be traversed in both direction.

> Both ends of a many-to-many relationship get automatic API access to
>   the other end. The API works just as a “backward” one-to-many
>   relationship, above.
>
> The only difference is in the attribute naming: The model that defines
>   the ManyToManyField uses the attribute name of that field itself,
>   whereas the “reverse” model uses the lowercased model name of the
>   original model, plus '_set' (just like reverse one-to-many
>   relationships).

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

Thus your models can be simplified.

```
class Group(models.Model):
   group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   group_contact= models.CharField(max_length=50)

   providers = models.ManyToMany(Provider, through='ProviderLocations')


class Provider(models.Model):
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now=false, auto_now_add=true)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=true, auto_now_add=true)
```

I am not quite sure why you are trying to create both a `GroupLocation` and `ProviderLocation` model. I do believe they can be merged.

Comment: you might be right, I have to rethink this.  I wasn't sure how the group would see the providers through the locations (as they are connected through group_locations).  I believe in my thinking the reason for the separation was that... a provider might be part of a group but at a specific location.     So above if I understand it:  a provider would be part of a group through a provider location (which has  a group location which is how it gets back to group) that works from the one line above?  Or was that what you were asking on the provider locations vs group locations?

Comment: Yes and that's what a ProviderLocation or GroupLocation model gives you. Having both means redundancy.

Comment: changed my comment.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your comment in full. "a provider might be part of a group but at a specific location" for example doesn't really sound like a many to many

Comment: Maybe a good way to say it is a provider is part of a group via the location they work at.   And a group can have many locations.  So the provider is part of a group to a specific location.  It might be they work at many of the groups locations, or just one.  But it is how they are related.

Comment: What's confusing here is the use of `part of` I think you just mean associated wtih. In that case yes, you can merge GroupLocation and ProviderLocation.

Comment: I think I see the disconnect.  To me I couldn't figure out how Providers related to groups except through their locations.  If  provider belongs to a group it does.  But it does so at a specific location the group has.  Not sure if that cleared it up at all.  Bah this logic is on the tip of my tongue and I am just not sure what captures it.

Comment: updated my question to reflect what I tried (based off your suggestion @e4c5

Comment: this is now a completely different question and it should have been posted as such

Comment: indeed. Fixed posted a new question. Thanks I think just talking this helps me wrap my head around this.