# django intermediate model with no foreign key error

Tags: python, django, django-models

Building some complex models for my django app and got some help here:

[Using ManyToMany through correctly for complex model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979749/using-manytomany-through-correctly-for-complex-model-in-django/37980278?noredirect=1#comment63450091_37980278)

To which the result was getting this far here:

> ipaswdb.ProviderLocations: (fields.E336) The model is used as an
>   intermediate model by 'ipaswdb.Group.providers', but it does not have
>   a foreign key to 'Group' or 'Provider'.

I mean yes the error is i n english but I do not know what it is really trying to tell me.

Full models below, but the idea was to have A group having many locations.

A provider belonging to a group via whichever location(s) they work at, secondly a provider can belong to many groups at many locations

```
Provider A -> location 1
         -> location 2
         -> location 3

Group 1 -> has a location 1
        -> has a location 2

Group 2 -> has a location 3
        -> has a location 4
```

Provider A belongs to group 1 and 2 via locations 1,2,3

My full models are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    providers = models.ManyToManyField('Provider', through='ProviderLocations')




class Provider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)



class ProviderLocations(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_location = models.ForeignKey('GroupLocations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class GroupLocations(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

I tried an edit on the ProviderLocations too with no results:

```
class ProviderLocations(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='GroupLocations')
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you set up the intermediary model, you explicitly specify foreign
>   keys to the models that are involved in the many-to-many relationship.
>   This explicit declaration defines how the two models are related

`Group` (not `GroupLocations`) and `Provider` are the ones in the M2M relationship so the throughmodel `ProviderLocations` must be linked to their `ForeignKeys`:

```
class ProviderLocations(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As is, each provider has a set of groups and each group has a set of group locations and you can walk through that hierarchy to fetch your objects.

You can make provider part of a group via group locations by eliminating the `ProviderLocations` model and using `GroupLocations` as the throughmodel:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    providers = models.ManyToManyField('Provider', through='GroupLocations')


class Provider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)


class GroupLocations(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: To me this doesn't capture the fact that a provider is part of a group via a groups location.

Comment: But with what you had, that's not the right way to implement your throughmodel, hence the error.

Comment: I didn't want to let this drag on in the comments but after getting to this project again and finding out that the admin doesn't show this relationship right.  For instance, the Provider in the groups does not show up as a field.  Also, the group locations requires (I know how to fix that) a provider, but if there is a provider for a new group location I have to add a whole nother group location to the DB.  This seems incorrect.  I did have another model with a many-to-many that shows up perfect in the admin interface.  With a nice list box multiple select etc not sure what piece I am missing.

Comment: Though this answer here did indeed fix the topic on hand of the foreign key error.

Comment: @Codejoy Well, if you think it fixed the problem at hand, you may consider accepting it

Comment: I did, it fixed the error in the title but still wasn't correct on my manytomany, but that was a totally different question so i opened a new one up :)

Comment: @Codejoy Ok, thanks for accepting. Did you find answer to your new question?

Comment: No someone flagged it as poorly written, I did edit it to be more concise.  I think I am overly depending on the Admin interface to test my models and that is part of the problem.  Inside the new question I explain that the billing model mostly looks good (goes one way but not other )  with my many to many, though still cannot get the group -> providers through location working in a many to many way.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115779/django-many-to-many-with-a-through-confusion?noredirect=1#comment63665349_38115779

Comment: I guess part of the problem is I am trying not to replicate data in the relational database...  and the way it was written above here, worked but would require a new group location created each time I wanted to add a provider to a group location.  which in reality if a grouplocation exists, I just need an intermediate table to add the provider to that location (with the ability to reach back to the group the location is a part of), well it is all in the other question I think.

Comment: @Codejoy I checked out the new question and I think it will be better received if you can simplify the model and use simpler examples. That would help better understand the problem.

Comment: Took your advice, tried to make it clearer with a use case.